# Redirecting to new url if redirection fails

Tags: java, redirect

I have a scenario in which I am redirecting to a `URL("xyz.com/redirect")` from Java. However in case the redirection `url("xyz.com/redirect")` is timed out or if the redirection url is down, I wanted to be notified, so that I can redirect to another `URL("xyz.com/handleTimeOut")`.

I cannot write any JavaScript code. All I have to handle this is at Java end. As far as I know, once I redirect, I lost control over the request, so I am not getting how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [HttpURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) where you can getResponseCode()

```
HttpURLConnection urlCon = new HttpURLConnection(new URL(<String URL>));
urlCon.setFollowRedirects(true);
urlCon.connect();
urlCon.getResponseCode() // here you get response code from server
```

If response code is Successful 2xx code you don't redirect otherwise open new connection to url you want to redirect if first url is timed out or if the redirection url is down

Comment: `urlCon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);`

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand how a redirect works. When you issue a response.sendRedirect a response is send to the browser with a http 302. At this point you have lost all control of the response on the server. The browser services the 302 directive and takes the user to the new URL.

That said, one possible way to do it is ping the redirect URL from the server, by say opening an http connection on the server side to the redirect url. If you received a valid response on the server only then redirect the client to this URL.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple and just create a custom error page for 402 or 504 status in which you include a link for xyz.com/handleTimeOut.